# How do I write this MySQL Query? (datetime)

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose I have a DateTime field called "time_before"

I want to insert a datetime that is 1 hour before the `now()` time.

```
INSERT INTO mytable(time_before) VALUES(now()-3600 seconds)...something like this, right?
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO mytable(`time_before`) VALUES(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's wrong database design.
why not to insert just current datetime? 
All calculations must be done at select time.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'd like to know what his advice is about, actually